# What does this react native detox build error mean?

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm very new to React Native and to detox. I followed their setup guide and when I went to execute the command `detox build --configuration android.emu.release` I was met with this lovely message:

```
Important: 'detox build' is a convenience shortcut for calling your own build command, as provided in the config file.
Failures in this build command are not the responsibility of Detox. You are responsible for maintaining this command.

Command failed: cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release
```

I don't know what this message means and googling it doesn't seem to bring up any results. So I'm hoping someone here can make more sense of it.

From what I can gather, this error means that the build command in my `detoxrc.js` file is failing. Is there a way to get more out of the error than just "something went wrong"?